# How to print the UNIX time in a binary representation in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, time

I recently came across information that on the 15th of May at 02:09:25 Unix time will be equal to `1010101010101010101010101010101` in binary representation.

I wanted to find out whether it is a fake or not, so I was trying to get the current Unix time in binary. I came up with a simple prompt like this:

```
$ date +%s | xxd -b
```

And I got a result like this:

```
0000000: 00110001 00110100 00110011 00110001 00110100 00110110  143146
0000006: 00110010 00110100 00110100 00110010 00001010           2442.
```

All in all, I got:

```
0011000100110100001100110011000100110100001101100011001000110100001101000011001000001010
```

But it shows **much** more digits than I expected. All the other variations were unsatisfactory as well such as `$ date "+%v %H:%M:%S" | xxd -b` or `$ date | xxd -b`.

I guess, this pair of `date` and `xxd` commands is not going to give me the expected result.

Could you tell me how can I get the current time in such a binary representation that I will get `1010101010101010101010101010101` on the 15th of May at 02:09:25?

---

#### Update:

OK, so using this online converter (http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html) I was able to get a reasonable number of digits. **How can I achieve the same using bash?**

Comment: Note that `date '+%s'` generated a string of decimal digits encoded in ASCII, and the `xxd -b` converted the ASCII character for each digit into binary (the `0011` followed by 4 bits is 48 + digit).

Comment: That's 0x55555555 in hexadecimal. And it means that, as of Fri 2015-05-15 02:09:25 UTC, we've used up 2/3 of the range of times from the epoch to 2*31-1 seconds, when 32-bit signed `time_t` overflows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "obase=2;$(date +%s)" |bc
```